# How to remove first 16 characters of each line in text file

Tags: regex

I am using Notepad++. I have already used some comands like `^.....` but it didn't work.

How can I remove first 16 characters from each line?

This is a text line.

`ramsandscriptstogetthebestinsightpossibleoutofitisthemostenjoyablepartofmyj`

When I replace `^.{16}` with an empty string, it gives me this:

`lepartofmyj`

I only want to remove first 16 characters.

Comment: For the record, the reason it replaces your test string with just `lepartofmyj` is because it replaces $[16 characters] with $[nothing] and then goes at it again, starting basically from the same spot and keeps repeating. It only stops when it gets to a string that counts for less than 16 characters. The difference with my regex is that I match the whole line and extract the part I want, it then moves on to a the point past that, makes another match if it can, and repeats.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me (`. matches newline` must be unchecked)

```
RegEx: ^.{1,16}(.*)$
Replace: \1
```

If you want not match lines less than 16 characters, leave them alone, you can use

```
RegEx: ^.{16}(.*)$
Replace: \1
```

I tested both expressions against

```
0123456789abcdefthis
0123456789abcdefis
0123456789abcdefa
0123456789abcdeftest
0123456789abcdef
of
things
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. This worked like a charm. Some just can't understand the question and start guessing :/

Answer (score 4):

One way is to :

`Find`:

```
^(.{0,16})
```

`Replace` : Leave it blank.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks BatScream.